# React Material UI classes with a parent Id

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Is there a way to add id to material ui class when react renders?

e.g.

from

```
.MuiInputLabel-outlined {
    z-index: 1;
    transform: translate(14px, 20px) scale(1);
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

to

```
#root-id-here .MuiInputLabel-outlined {
    z-index: 1;
    transform: translate(14px, 20px) scale(1);
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: Are you using the `InputLabel` component or does this result from using the `TextField` component?

Comment: @hotpink it's TextField component :)

Comment: Can you supply a codesandbox with your code please?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are two ways to solve this

1. **Javascript** :- `const test = document.getElementByClassName(‘.MuiInputLabel-outlined’); test.setAttribute(‘id’,‘IdName’);`
2. **Jquery** :- `.$('MuiInputLabel-outlined').addID('some-class');`

Comment: I'm talking about updating the css codes react render with material UI